# Ip addressing between routers

Tags: router, ip, subnet

I'm trying to get a theoritical problem I found in an old book (keep that in mind).

In the book, there is an example where a company with an isp connection and a network called 'Gigabit Ethernet' and the company has like 3 branches (with 2 LANs at each branch and 5 host at each LAN) away of the main offices, as they want to expand to another 3 branches.

The connection between the main offices and the branches is by one main router and three other for each branch where they connect only with the main router.

For our circumstances, we need 19 subnets with the ip address that the company has (f.e. 200.20.2.0/24)

So for 19 subnets we need 5 bits, thus the subnet mask will be /24 + 5 bits = /29 or 255.255.255.248

Each ip address is 8 steps away from the one before it and the one after it (f.e 200.20.2.8->200.20.2.16->200.20.2.24).

The way the book has the connections (and I upload this because my bad english can't make the network really clear) is this:

[in the photo, the other 3 that the company wants to expand to doesn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5WXb.png)

The catch is that this problem wants the same subnet mask for ALL of the subnets, so no variable subnet masks for this.

I'm really a newbie at ip addressing and i have a hard time understanding the addressing between the routers. My first though was that two routers can have a common ip interface that signals the connection between them, but I found nothing like this on the web. Only a use of two ip interfaces with another mask.

[What I was trying to do looked like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TsoM.png)

can you describe to me how ip addressing between two routers work?
how can I indeed address the whole network using the same /29 mask?

Comment: Did you mean "wants" or "doesn't want"?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It indeed wants the same mask for all the subnets.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework question...

Answer (score 0):

> The catch is that this problem wants the same subnet mask for ALL of the subnets, so no variable subnet masks for this.

These have nothing to do with each other.

The 'Variable' in VLSM only means that the mask does not depend on the address itself – for comparison, in the Classful era, the mask would have been determined by the leading address bits.

However, it doesn't mean the mask has to vary for any *other* reason, and any given prefix length still results in the exact same mask. So if you declare that all your subnets are /29's, then they *will* be /29's, which means 255.255.255.248 as the subnet mask for all of them.

The only wrong part of your drawing is that *both ends of a link* must, of course, belong to the same subnet. For example, if your router "R" uses the 200.20.2.24/29 subnet for "WAN 1", then router "R1" must use the same .24/29 subnet for its "WAN 1"-facing interface as well.

---

Also, to simplify routing, you should allocate subnets such that they could be easily summarized. For example, since you have 4 routers, then you could divide the /24 like this;

- R1 gets the prefix 200.20.2.64/26 (with subnets .64/29, .72/29, .80/29…)
- R2 gets the prefix 200.20.2.128/26 (with subnets .128/29, .136/29, .144/29…)
- R3 gets...

(This would have *zero* effect on the actual subnets being used; it merely simplifies routing configuration by grouping the same router's subnets under the same prefix.)

Comment: So, between the routers R and R1 (or R2,R3) I should/ve put only one address, if I undestood well. So there's no need for different addresses at the edges of the link? Seems like I have to rerun the whole book.

Comment: Huh? Are you mixing up addresses and subnets? Addresses belong to a device so they must be different; subnets, on the other hand, belong to the link itself.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the mix up. I was talking about the addresses of the subnets. I meant if it was more "right" for the solution to be like this: http://i64.tinypic.com/2s64kgl.png

Comment: Yes, that would work.