# How to access LAN subnets from other subnets with interzone firewalling on the same router?

Tags: networking, router, routing, lan, subnet

<sup>*This has probably been asked before, but I have no idea what this is called or what search terms to use 
 ([this](https://superuser.com/a/1152534/529800) answer kind of seemed what I'd need, but I'm unsure)*</sup>

I have a [WRT1900ACS](https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt_ac_series) running [OpenWrt 23.05](https://openwrt.org/releases/23.05/start) that has five LAN subnets:

- **`lan`:** [`10.1.0.0/19`](https://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.19.0.1&mask1=19&mask2=)
- **`net1`:** `10.1.15.0/28`
- **`net2`:** `10.1.20.0/27`
- **`net3`:** `10.1.25.0/27`
- **`net4`:** `10.1.25.28/30`

I wanted the `net1 - 4` subnets to be sanely numbered, which is why `lan`'s CIDR is `/19`, as my understanding *(which may be incorrect)* is if `lan` was set to a subnet mask encompassing the subnets of `net3 - 4` and `net3` set to a subnet mask encompassing `net4`, I'd be able to access devices on them from a device on `lan` and a device on `net3`:

- PC [`lan`] → Airplay server [`net3`]
- PC [`lan`] → Printer [`net4`]
- PC [`net3`] → Printer [`net4`]

What I've tried in the firewall separately and together *(commented out in firewall config)*:

- allowing interzone forwarding
- specifying individual interzone forwarding rules

---

### Configs:

- **[`/etc/config/network`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/basic-networking):**

  ```ini
  #

        ##::[[---  OpenWrt WAN Network Config  ---]]::##

  # ===========================================================
                    ##----- Global -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # https://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.0.0.1&mask1=19&mask2=

  # ===========================================================
            ##----- Active Networks w/ WAN -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # Loopback #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config interface 'loopback'
      option  device          'lo'
      option  proto           'static'
      option  ipaddr          127.0.0.1
      option  netmask         255.0.0.0

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: WAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config device
      option  name            'wan'

  config interface 'wan'
      option  device          'wan'
      option  proto           'dhcp'

  config interface 'wan6'
      option  ifname          'wan'
      option  proto           'dhcpv6'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: LAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config device
      option  name            'br-lan'
      option  type            'bridge'
      list    ports           'lan1'
      list    ports           'lan4'

  config interface 'lan'
      option  device          'br-lan'
      option  proto           'static'
      option  dns             '208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220'
      option  force_link      1
      option  ip6assign       60
      option  broadcast       10.1.31.255
      option  ipaddr          10.1.0.1
      option  netmask         255.255.224.0

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net1 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config interface 'net1'
      option  ifname          'net1'
      option  type            'bridge'
      option  proto           'static'
      option  dns             '208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220'
      option  broadcast       10.1.15.15
      option  delegate        0
      option  ipaddr          10.1.15.1
      option  netmask         255.255.255.240

      # vLAN: net2 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config device
      option  name            'br-net2'
      option  type            'bridge'
      list    ports           'lan2'

  config interface 'net3'
      option  device          'br-net2'
      option  proto           'static'
      option  dns             '208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220'
      option  broadcast       10.1.20.31
      option  ipaddr          10.1.20.1
      option  netmask         255.255.255.224

      # vLAN: net3 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config device
      option  name            'br-net3'
      option  type            'bridge'
      list    ports           'lan3'

  config interface 'net3'
      option  device          'br-net3'
      option  proto           'static'
      option  dns             '208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220'
      option  broadcast       10.1.25.31
      option  ipaddr          10.1.25.1
      option  netmask         255.255.255.224

      # vLAN: net4 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config interface 'net4'
      option  ifname          'net4'
      option  type            'bridge'
      option  proto           'static'
      option  broadcast       10.1.25.31
      option  delegate        0
      option  ipaddr          10.1.25.29
      option  netmask         255.255.255.252
  ```
- **[`/etc/config/firewall`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/firewall_configuration):**

  ```ini
  #

        ##::[[---  OpenWrt WAN Firewall Config  ---]]::##

  # ===========================================================
                  ##----- Scripts -----##
  # ===========================================================

  config include
      option  path                  '/etc/firewall. User'

  # ===========================================================
                ##----- Default Zone -----##
  # ===========================================================

  config defaults
      option  input                 'ACCEPT'
      option  forward               'REJECT'
      option  output                'ACCEPT'
      option  log_limit             '10/second'
      option  custom_chains         1
      option  drop_invalid          1
      option  log                   1
      option  synflood_protect      1
      option  tcp_syncookies        1
      option  tcp_window_scaling    1

  # ===========================================================
                ##----- NAT Redirects -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # SSH #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------

  # ===========================================================
                    ##----- Zones -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # WAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config zone
      option  name            'wan'
      list    network         'wan'
      list    network         'wan6'
      option  input           'REJECT'
      option  forward         'REJECT'
      option  output          'ACCEPT'
      option  masq            1
      option  mtu_fix         1

  # ===========================================================

      # LAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config zone
      option  name            'lan'
      list    network         'lan'
      option  input           'ACCEPT'
      option  forward         'ACCEPT'
      option  output          'ACCEPT'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             'lan'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow LAN → WRT1900ACS (DHCP Requests)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             '*'
      option  dest            'lan'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow WRT1900ACS → LAN (DHCP Renew)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'tcp udp'
      option  src             'lan'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '53'
      option  name            'Allow LAN → WRT1900ACS (DNS)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'icmp'
      option  src             'lan'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  name            'Allow LAN → WRT1900ACS (ICMP)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'lan'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  name            'Allow LAN → WRT1900ACS'

  # config rule
  #   option  target          'ACCEPT'
  #   option  proto           'all'
  #   option  src             'lan'
  #   option  dest            'net3'
  #   option  name            'Allow LAN → net3'

  # ===========================================================
                    ##----- Rules -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net1 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config zone
      option  name            'net1'
      list    network         'net1'
      option  input           'REJECT'
      option  forward         'REJECT'
      option  output          'ACCEPT'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow net1 → WRT1900ACS (DHCP Requests)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             '*'
      option  dest            'net1'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow WRT1900ACS → net1 (DHCP Renew)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'tcp udp'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '53'
      option  name            'Allow net1 → WRT1900ACS (DNS)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'icmp'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  name            'Allow net1 → WRT1900ACS (ICMP)'

  config rule
      option  target          'DROP'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_ip         '10.1.15.15'
      option  name            'Drop net1 → WRT1900ACS (Broadcast)'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            'lan'
      option  name            'Reject net1 → LAN'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            'net2'
      option  name            'Reject net1 → net2'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            'net3'
      option  name            'Reject net1 → net3'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            'net4'
      option  name            'Reject net1 → net4'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net2 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config zone
      option  name            'net2'
      list    network         'net2'
      option  input           'ACCEPT'
      option  forward         'REJECT'
      option  output          'ACCEPT'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             'net2'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow net2 → WRT1900ACS (DHCP Requests)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             '*'
      option  dest            'net2'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow WRT1900ACS → net2 (DHCP Renew)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'tcp udp'
      option  src             'net2'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '53'
      option  name            'Allow net2 → WRT1900ACS (DNS)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'icmp'
      option  src             'net2'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  name            'Allow net2 → WRT1900ACS (ICMP)'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net2'
      option  dest            'net1'
      option  name            'Reject net2 → net1'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net3 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config zone
      option  name            'net3'
      list    network         'net3'
      option  input           'ACCEPT'
      option  forward         'REJECT'
      option  output          'ACCEPT'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             'net3'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow net3 → WRT1900ACS (DHCP Requests)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             '*'
      option  dest            'net3'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow WRT1900ACS → net3 (DHCP Renew)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'tcp udp'
      option  src             'net3'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '53'
      option  name            'Allow net3 → WRT1900ACS (DNS)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'icmp'
      option  src             'net3'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  name            'Allow net3 → WRT1900ACS (ICMP)'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net3'
      option  dest            'lan'
      option  name            'Reject net3 → LAN'

  config rule
      option  target          'REJECT'
      option  proto           'all'
      option  src             'net3'
      option  dest            'net1'
      option  name            'Reject net3 → net1'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net4 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config zone
      option  name            'net4'
      list    network         'net4'
      option  input           'ACCEPT'
      option  forward         'REJECT'
      option  output          'ACCEPT'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             'net4'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow net4 → WRT1900ACS (DHCP Requests)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'udp'
      option  src             '*'
      option  dest            'net4'
      option  dest_port       '67:68'
      option  name            'Allow WRT1900ACS → net4 (DHCP Renew)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'tcp udp'
      option  src             'net4'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  dest_port       '53'
      option  name            'Allow net4 → WRT1900ACS (DNS)'

  config rule
      option  target          'ACCEPT'
      option  proto           'icmp'
      option  src             'net4'
      option  dest            '*'
      option  name            'Allow net4 → WRT1900ACS (ICMP)'

  # ===========================================================
              ##----- Interzone Forwarding  -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: LAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config forwarding
      option  src             'lan'
      option  dest            'wan'

  # config forwarding
  #   option  src             'lan'
  #   option  dest            'net3'

  # config forwarding
  #   option  src             'lan'
  #   option  dest            'net4'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net1 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config forwarding
      option  src             'net1'
      option  dest            'wan'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net2 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config forwarding
      option  src             'net2'
      option  dest            'wan'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net3 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config forwarding
      option  src             'net3'
      option  dest            'wan'

  # config forwarding
  #   option  src             'net3'
  #   option  dest            'net4'

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net4 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  # config forwarding
  #   option  src             'net4'
  #   option  dest            'lan'

  # config forwarding
  #   option  src             'net4'
  #   option  dest            'net3'
  ```
- **[`/etc/config/dhcp`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/dhcp):**

  ```ini
  #

        ##::[[---  OpenWrt WAN DHCP #config  ---]]::##

  # ===========================================================
                ##----- IPv4 DNS Server -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # DNS Masq #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dnsmasq
      option  domain              'WRT'
      option  configdir           '/tmp/dnsmasq.d'
      option  local               '/lan/'
      option  leasefile           '/tmp/dhcp.leases'
      option  resolvfile          '/tmp/resolv.conf.d/resolv.conf.auto'
      option  ednspacket_max      1232
      option  authoritative       1
      option  boguspriv           1
      option  domainneeded        1
      option  cachesize           1000
      option  expandhosts         1
      option  filter_aaaa         0
      option  filter_a            0
      option  filterwin2k         1
      option  localise_queries    1
      option  localservice        1
      option  logquerries         0
      option  nonegcache          0
      option  nonwildcard         1
      option  quietdhcp           1
      option  readethers          1
      option  rebind_localhost    1
      option  rebind_protection   1
      option  sequential_ip       1

  # ===========================================================
                ##----- IPv6 DNS Server -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # oDHCPd #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config odhcpd 'odhcpd'
      option  leasefile           '/tmp/hosts/odhcpd'
      option  leasetrigger        '/usr/sbin/odhcpd-update'
      option  loglevel            4
      option  maindhcp            0

  # ===========================================================
                ##----- DHCP Settings -----##
  # ===========================================================

      # WAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dhcp 'wan'
      option  interface           'wan'
      option  ignore              1

  # ===========================================================

      # VLAN: LAN #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dhcp 'lan'
      option  interface           'lan'
      option  dhcpv4              'server'
      option  dhcpv6              'server'
      option  leasetime           '24h'
      option  ra                  'server'
      list    ra_flags            'managed-config'
      list    ra_flags            'other-config'
      option  force               1
      option  limit               1
      option  ra_management       1
      option  ra_slaac            1
      option  start               21

  # Static IPs
  # -----------------------------------------------------------

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net1 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dhcp 'net1'
      option  interface           'net1'
      option  leasetime           '24h'
      option  force               1
      option  limit               12
      option  start               3

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net2 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dhcp 'net2'
      option  interface           'net2'
      option  leasetime           '24h'
      option  force               1
      option  limit               12
      option  start               2

  # Static IPs
  # -----------------------------------------------------------

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net3 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dhcp 'net3'
      option  interface           'net3'
      option  leasetime           '24h'
      option  force               1
      option  limit               1
      option  start               25

  # Static IPs
  # -----------------------------------------------------------

  # ===========================================================

      # vLAN: net4 #
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  config dhcp 'net4'
      option  interface           'net4'
      option  leasetime           '24h'
      option  force               1
      option  limit               1
      option  start               30

  # Static IPs
  # -----------------------------------------------------------
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted the `net1 - 4` subnets to be sanely numbered, which is why `lan`'s CIDR is `/19`, as my understanding *(which may be incorrect)* is if `lan` was set to a subnet mask encompassing the subnets of `net3 - 4` and `net3` set to a subnet mask encompassing `net4`, I'd be able to access devices on them from a device on `lan` and a device on `net3`:

No, that's the exact opposite of what you want; subnets should never overlap in any way. Don't think of `lan` as a "parent" of other subnets. (*Routes* can overlap though; it's still valid to have a single /19 or /16 route 'via some other gateway' that encompasses all subnets.)

Subnets are connected only through the router; in order for hosts from subnet A to access anything in subnet B, they must go through the router (i.e. send packets to the router's MAC address).

But if the subnets overlap, then hosts in subnet A will think that the destination (belonging to subnet B) is in the *same* subnet as them (i.e. looking as if it's part of subnet A) – and same-subnet hosts by definition are accessible without going through the gateway, in general.

So the source host will instead try to make ARP queries for the destination IP directly, coming up with nothing – well, unless the router had proxy-ARP enabled (which is normally not enabled; I think only ancient Cisco IOS defaulted to enabling it).

It doesn't matter that the *router* knows the correct routes (`10.1.15.0/28 via net1` will take priority over `10.1.0.0/17 via lan`) if the packets never make it to the router to begin with.

---

- That aside, this doesn't quite look "sanely numbered" in general. With only five subnets, you have *plenty* of space to make all of them nice round /24's; there is no need to squeeze them to the smallest possible size – there is exactly zero difference in performance between a /16 with five hosts and a /29 with five hosts.
- Also, as I recall, AirPlay was strongly reliant on mDNS-based auto-discovery, which does not work across subnets unless the router has a repeater specifically for that. (Regular IP routing won't do it, not even multicast routing.) For OpenWrt, [umdns](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/mdns) seems to do this; for general Linux, avahi-daemon can act as a relay.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! =] If I'm understanding this correctly, your answer I linked to at the very top is also the answer to this? _(Should I also recommend to close my question because it's a duplicate?)_ Also, what is the correct term for this specific type of routing?

Comment: Hmm, no, I don't think the other question is really related at all (except I guess for listing a few example subnets?) And, there isn't any particular term, I'd say it's the most generic kind of IP routing there is.